# jquery appendTo multiple items to one container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues getting this to work. When I look at the HTML in firebug it shows that there are 2  objects inside my container but only 1 img shows!

I have some very simple code:

```
var img1 = $("<img />", {src : "myimg.png" });
var img2 = $("<img />", {src : "myimg2.png" });
img1.appendTo("#div");
img2.appendTo("#div");

<div id="div"></div>
```

But only the first image will show, if I comment out the first `appendTo` then the second image will show, or if I reverse the order the 2nd will show and not the first.

Comment: Does the image exists? http://jsfiddle.net/yodapt/2V4GX/

Comment: yes, as stated above 'if I comment out the first appendTo then the second image will show, or if I reverse the order the 2nd will show and not the first.'

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2YtBe/ Are you executing the script after the DOM is scriptable? (ie. in the document ready function)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually related to appendTo but my `#div` and images sizes. strange.

Answer (score 0):

May I show you how to append elements with native javascript? It is faster and very similar syntax. Plus, it will make you a better programmer.

First of all, checkout javascript templating if you haven't already. I personally use http://handlebarsjs.com/.

Anyway, here's how to do what you want with javascript.

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById("div");
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); 

["myimg.png", "myimg2.png"].forEach(function(src) {
 var element = document.createElement("img");
 element.src = src;
 fragment.appendChild(element);
}); 

parentElement.appendChild(fragment);
```